# Disable tabbar item - Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

How do I disable a particular tabbar item? Something like for the 3rd icon...

```
self.tabBarItem.items![2].enabled = false
```

There must be a way of doing such a simple task as a one liner? 
The above doesn't work...

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `self.tabBarItem.items![2].setEnabled(true, forSegmentAtIndex: 2);` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
if  let arrayOfTabBarItems = tabBarViewController.tabBar.items as! AnyObject as? NSArray,tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[2] as? UITabBarItem {
        tabBarItem.enabled = false
    }
```

Comment: Had to tweak it a bit for Swift 3:
       
        if  let arrayOfTabBarItems = tabBarController?.tabBar.items as AnyObject as? NSArray,let tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[2] as? UITabBarItem {
            tabBarItem.isEnabled = true
        }

Answer (score 10):

Here's my code for doing the same, using **Swift 3:**

```
    let tabBarControllerItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items

    if let tabArray = tabBarControllerItems {
        tabBarItem1 = tabArray[0]
        tabBarItem2 = tabArray[1]

        tabBarItem1.isEnabled = false
        tabBarItem2.isEnabled = false    
    }
```

Just put the block of code above in the `viewDidLoad()` method for starters and don't forget to create the `tabBarItem` variables and you're all good to go from there!

Answer (score 10):

In case someone is looking how to **disable all tab bar items**:

```
if let items = tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
        items.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

SWIFT 4.2

```
if let arrayOfTabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as AnyObject as? NSArray,let 
   tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[1] as? UITabBarItem {
   tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To disable a tabBarItem on a single view (and re-enable it when the view changes):

In the **Class definition**, create placeholder Class variables for your UITabBarItems:

```
var tabBarItemONE: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem()
var tabBarItemTWO: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem()
etc...
```

Then, in **viewWillAppear**, disable the items as you wish:

```
let tabBarControllerItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items

if let arrayOfTabBarItems = tabBarControllerItems as! AnyObject as? NSArray{

    tabBarItemONE = arrayOfTabBarItems[0] as! UITabBarItem
    tabBarItemONE.enabled = false

    tabBarItemTWO = arrayOfTabBarItems[1] as! UITabBarItem
    tabBarItemTWO.enabled = false

}
```

In **viewWillDisappear**, re-enable the items:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    tabBarItemONE.enabled = true
    tabBarItemTWO.enabled = true

}
```

Answer (score 3):

***Swift 5***

You can enable or disable a single tabbar button with this code.

```
var controller = YourViewController()
controller.tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the one-liner:

In Objective C, that line of code works in `viewDidLoad:`.

In Swift, it doesn't work in `viewDidLoad()`, but works in `viewWillAppear()`.

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension for this, base of "Aditya Koukuntla" answer:

```
 extension UIViewController {

    func enableTabbarItems(_ items: [Int]) {
        disableAllTabbarItems()
        if let arrayOfTabBarItems = tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray? {
            for i in 0..<arrayOfTabBarItems.count {
                if items.contains(i) {
                    if let tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[i] as? UITabBarItem {
                        tabBarItem.isEnabled = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func disableAllTabbarItems() {
        if let arrayOfTabBarItems = tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray? {
            for i in 0..<arrayOfTabBarItems.count {
                if let tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[i] as? UITabBarItem {
                    tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty great

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do it, with only one line of code:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[2].isEnabled=false
```